# Is this sentence correct? "Add some lemon juice to it if you wish to."

Tags: grammar

I've learned that we can add "to" after  "want" just like the sentence,"You can do it later if you want (to)."  Yet, I am wondering if the sentence below is also possible.

Add some lemon juice to it if you wish to.

Without "to" sounds more natural to me. Can we add "to" here?

Answer (score 1):

If it's part of a recipe, it would be something like:

> Add lemon juice **if liked/if required/to taste.**

(the last one means 'according to your own personal taste').

If it's something said in conversation, it would indeed sound more natural without **to,** especially if you have already said **to it** - but it isn't wrong to add **to**.

Comment: I've always assumed ***if liked*** implies *Add X if cook and/or diners like it, **otherwise don't add X***, whereas ***to taste*** to me implies *Add **the amount of** X that suits cook and/or diners palates* (with the implication that you always need ***some*** X - it's just a question of ***how much***). Not sure what ***if required*** would mean though. By who, and why?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - When I was a child I once read on a jar of peanut butter "Add salt to taste". Not being familiar with that sense of the word, I understood it to mean "You must add salt to give it any flavour", and my mother explained that it meant "if you feel that it needs it".

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm a native speaker, I often feel the "idiomatic standard" here is a little "peculiar"...

> *Add [some] lemon juice [to it] **if liked.***

(Where "some" and "to it" wouldn't *normally* be included.)

One argument in favour of this remarkably "clipped" style is it's unspecified whether it's the ***cook*** or the ***diners*** who might or might not like whatever can be optionally added. But that's part of what makes me feel that *syntactically* it's a bit odd.

Maybe we could say it's an example of "recipese" (compare "headlinese" and "journalese", where *brevity* is the guiding principle). All I know it that's how they usually phrase it in recipes.

---

Because OP's alternative is already "not standard", it's a bit meaningless to ask whether it's idiomatic to append that final infinitive marker. But it's *totally* non-idiomatic to include the *full* "omitted text"...

> *Add some lemon juice to it if you wish **to add some lemon juice to it***.

Comment: Just to be even more cussed, and clipping it about as far as it will go, "Lemon juice, optional." …or, more conversationally, "Maybe try a little lemon juice." The thing, as you note, about recipese is much of it is optional, or to taste. Imagine "We start by taking two small chicken breasts & 42 finely-diced chillis…"